# Inline tikz alignment — use as \newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to use `tikzpicture` as a command in text seamlessly.

I am trying to do the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\textrot}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[scale=-1] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

My beautiful text

My \textrot{beautiful} text

\end{document}
```

But everything is shifted. My goal is to modify the text with `tikz` inline, without affeting other words.

[image]

**Note:** I am not exactly looking for the way of reflecting a word. I am going to use tikzpicture as command for other porpuses too.

Comment: you are missing a `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}` so adding a space to the output

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it doesn't preven the shifting and `beautiful` is still up high.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the default baseline is at the bottom of the generated box; nodes in `tikz` have a default padding (don't remember how much) and this is why results in this... apart for the extra spaces. Adding `draw` as options in the box will show it.

Comment: ah the sep yes I deleted my previous comment thanks

Comment: This is just a suggestion, but the title of your question is not very specific about your apparent request. You should consider making it more precise.

Comment: @BambOo could you give me a piece of advice how I can improve it?

Comment: Maybe solmething like *Inline tikz alignment* ... but it has to come from you, not me :). And as it is your problem, it must be formulated with your words

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to say to the `tikzpicture` where the baseline must go (I added a letter with a descendent because it can matter...):

Notice that you must define what aligned means for you. In the fist case, the two baselines of the text are aligned. In the second case, the top of the reflected text in on the baseline. In the last case, the center of the text is on the baseline.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\textrot}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base)]
        \node[scale=-1, inner sep=0pt](A) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\textrotb}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.north)]
        \node[scale=-1, inner sep=0pt](A) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\textrotc}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]% baseline at 0,0 of the picture
        \node[scale=-1, inner sep=0pt](A) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

My beautiful text

My \textrot{beautjful} text

My \textrotb{beautjful} text

My \textrotc{beautjful} text
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you add a `draw, red` to the node options you'll see it better:

[image]

You can clearly use a definition with an optional argument for the baseline anchor, like

```
\newcommand{\textrot}[2][base]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.#1)]
        \node[draw, red, thin, scale=-1, inner sep=0pt](A) {#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Comment: you still missing the `%` so getting a space added after the picture (see comment below the question)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle blush. I blame `vim` (got the wrong cut buffer)

Comment: if you are using vim it's surprising you managed to edit it at all, emacs is the one true way.

Comment: But look, reflected "beautiful" is not aligned with the normal one, and "text" is not exactly under the original one.

Comment: Because you must define what aligned means for you. In the fist case, the two baselines of the text are aligned. In the second case now, the top of the reflected text in on the baseline. In the last case, the center of the text is on the baseline. And in all cases, the comments of @DavidCarlisle and the `inner sep` explain what was happening to the position of the "text" after. Have you read the manual about `tikz` nodes and anchors?

Comment: After you've edited it became what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: I have tested it out: for that I removed `scale=-1` in order to ensure it is at the right spot. I have also changed to `baseline=(A.south)` and it almost percise, but lifted up a bit. How can it be fixed? 
https://imgur.com/ZK7lGAy

Comment: +1 perhaps it's be worth considering a version that has an optional argument that allows the user to tweak the baseline on a per case basis....?

Comment: @antshar you should post a question, I treid it but it seems to work (first line with `base`, second one with `south`): https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNR39.png

Comment: @Rmano `base` works for me. Thanks!